# jQuery .load by element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to load an element from a webpage via ID.

My code reads the url from the 'href' attribute of the  tag and then loads the page. I'm stripping the document anchor.

This script **works** but won't discard the surround elements and loads the entire page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var a_href = $('#pycom').attr('href').split('#');
    $('div#pop-up').load(a_href[0] + '#synopsis');
});
</script>

<body>
    <a id="pycom" href="content/documentation/CommandsPython/ls.html#hFlags">ls</a>
</body>
```

- http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/ls.html

The above link exists locally on my server (XAMPP) as per the 'html' code above.

Below is the element I would like to extract.

```
<p id="synopsis">
    <code>
        xform([objects...], 
        [<a href="#flagabsolute">absolute</a>=<i>boolean</i>], 
        [<a href="#flagboundingBox">boundingBox</a>=<i>boolean</i>],
        .....
        .....

    </code>
```

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: It should work fine. any error in console?

Comment: why are you writing $('div#pop-up').load(a_href[0] + ' #synopsis'); ? You can write only $('div#pop-up').load(a_href[0]); to load the page. why do you need to add '#synopsis' inside load() function?

Comment: as per [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/) I can pass the element id to load that fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved. I was using **jQuery 2.4.1** which apparently has a bug that is supposed to be fixed.. but appears to be not??  see here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14773

I am instead using **jQuery 1.11.3**

below is my final code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="content/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var moveLeft = -10;
        var moveDown = 10;

        $('a#pycom').hover(function(e) {
            var a_href = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
            $('#pop-up').load(a_href[0] + ' #synopsis');
            $('div#pop-up').show().css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', ((e.width/100)*1) + moveLeft);
        }, function() {
            $('div#pop-up').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following method using **.get** also works exactly the same except gives the benefit of being able to process the returned string in the callback.. in this case the trailing section of the requested selected element...  very nice stuff.

```
$('a#pycom').hover(function(e) {
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    $.get(a_href[0], function(response) {
        $('#pop-up').html($(response).filter('#synopsis').html().split('<br>')[0]);
        });    
    });
```

Now owning jQuery like a BOSS!!

[image: jQuery .get in action!]

Thank you to all those who helped out.

Chur!

J

Answer (score 0):

```
At first get your page, and then inside the 
content find your element with id named 'synopsis' as below:

 var a_href = $('#pycom').attr('href').split('#');
 $("div#pop-up").load(a_href[0] + " #synopsis" );
```

It should work, but before that check whether your browser supports mixed content. If your url contains http inside https then browser may not support, In that case you have to disallow the checking in the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm host my site locally with xampp and the page I want to load via jQuery is also locally stored.  So there's not security issues. The jQuery actually works but is won't discard everything outside the tag.

Answer (score -1):

You should not give any space in the URL. There is a space before ' #synopsis'.

```
 $('div#pop-up').load(a_href[0] + '#synopsis');
```

Comment: right..  thanks for that... actually everywhere I had read thus far and all the examples insisted on adding the space.  But while this now loads the page, it won't discard the rest of the surrounding elements.

Comment: thankyou for your help but it still won't load only the required fragment which is what i' really trying to solve.